# Fastest way to generate property in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, keyboard-shortcuts

1. I generate a property with "prop TAB TAB"
2. Cursor is positioned on the data type, and I change it normally
3. But, after that, I need to select its name, either with the mouse or using `CTRL` + `Shift`

Is there some faster way to automatically select property's name after autogenerating it with a shortcut (prop TAB TAB)?

Comment: In step 3, You can select the name with TAB, after you typed the type, and then press enter

Comment: Use the tab key to select the parameter you want to modify. You can also search for snippet customizations to create your own snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to do it are:

1. I generate a property with `prop TAB TAB`
2. Cursor is positioned on the data type, change the data type if needed
3. Hit `TAB` again to navigate to the property name and change it